# Cloning div on click breaks when moving the button out of container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I found this nifty js fiddle and it does nearly exactly what I need

However its cloning the parent of the button and id like to have the button separate from the actual div being cloned. *(if you put the clone button back into the container with the remove button it works fine again)*

**In all I am trying to accomplish 3 things.**

**1.** Have the button outside of the div that's being duplicated (1 button)

**2.** Limit the number of duplication's to a total of 6. (or any changeable variable)

**3.** Update the `<h4>` content and change the number 1 to the next number. ie: (1-6)

I'm not very JS savvy although I do dabble. If anyone has the time to help me figure out the above it would be beyond appreciated! Here's the **[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/1890/)** I've been playing with.

Thanks!

```
var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;

function clone(){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
        .appendTo("body")
        .attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex)
        .find("*")
        .each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 3) {
                this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
            }
        })
        .on('click', 'button.clone', clone)
        .on('click', 'button.remove', remove);
    cloneIndex++;
}
function remove(){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
}
$("button.clone").on("click", clone);

$("button.remove").on("click", remove);
```

Comment: on click of clone you want to duplicate .clonedInput1 div right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the folowing is what you're trying to acheive, you have to add another variables `cloned_nbr` and `clones_limit` to control the cloned divs:

```js
var cloneIndex = 1;
var clones_limit = 4;
var cloned_nbr = $(".clonedInput").length-1; //Exclude Default (first) div 

function clone()
{
  if(cloned_nbr<clones_limit)
  {
    cloneIndex++;
    cloned_nbr++;

    var new_clone =  $(".clonedInput").first().clone();

    new_clone.attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex);
    new_clone.find(".label-nbr").text(cloneIndex);
    new_clone.find(".category").attr("id","category"+cloneIndex);
    new_clone.find(".remove").attr("id","remove"+cloneIndex);
    new_clone.on('click', 'button.clone', clone);
    new_clone.on('click', 'button.remove', remove);

    $(".clone").before(new_clone);
  }
}
function remove(){
  if(cloneIndex>1){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
    cloned_nbr--;
  }
}
$("button.clone").on("click", clone);

$("button.remove").on("click", remove);
```

```css
body { padding: 10px;}

.clonedInput { padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #def; margin-bottom: 10px; }

.clonedInput div { margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
  <div>
    <label for="txtCategory" class="">Learning category <span class="label-nbr">1</span><span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
    <select class="category" name="txtCategory[]" id="category1">
      <option value="">Please select</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="clone">Clone</button>
```

Comment: Can I ask how do i change the buttons to id's in the script? I am actually gonna use div buttons and now its not liking me putting an id in place of the button.

Comment: if you have a moment would love for you to check out my new issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663974/cloned-divs-are-not-staying-in-the-grid-correctly

Comment: Yes with pleasure , `new_clone.show(".remove").attr("id","remove"+cloneIndex);` should be `new_clone.find(".remove").attr("id","remove"+cloneIndex);`. replace `show` by `find`.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the last occurence of `.clonedInput` and clone that, then insert it after the original element:

```js
var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;

function clone(){
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;
    if (cloneIndex > 6) return;

    $source = $(".clonedInput").last();
    $source.clone()
        .insertAfter($source)
        .attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex)
        .find("*")
        .each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 3) {
                this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
            }
        })
        .on('click', 'button.remove', remove)
        .find('label').html('Learning category ' + cloneIndex + ' <span class="requiredField">*</span>');
}
function remove(){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
}
$("button.clone").on("click", clone);

$("button.remove").on("click", remove);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
    <div>
        <label for="txtCategory" class="">Learning category 1 <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
        <select class="" name="txtCategory[]" id="category1">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
   
    <div class="actions">
        <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="clone">Clone</button>
```

Comment: if you have a moment would love for you to check out my new issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663974/cloned-divs-are-not-staying-in-the-grid-correctly

Answer (score 0):

I'd initialize plain block as template and use it as clone base.

HTML

```
<div class="box-wrap">
     <button class="clone">Clone</button>
</div>
```

Full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jeafgilbert/tfFLt/1898/